# Как получить SHA последнего коммита?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Есть репозиторий на Bitbucket с несколькими ветками.

На сервере необходимо получить SHA последнего коммита, который относится к ветке production.

Эта команда работает некорректно:

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, верную команду для получения SHA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Штатный способ:

```
git show-ref --heads --hash production
```

> гит, покажи-ка мне из **локальных веток** (`--heads`) **хэш** (`--hash`) ветки `production`

А ещё можно просто залезть прямо в папку с данными репозитория, там ветка это просто файл с SHA последнего коммита внутри:

```
cat .git/refs/heads/production
```

...потому что это всё, что из себя представляет ветка, это просто хэш её последнего коммита.

---

Если ветка не локальная, `--heads` нужно опустить и использовать название ветки вместе с её источником. После клонирования исходный репозиторий указан в `origin`, так что:

```
git show-ref --hash origin/production
```

Это работает **почти** всегда, поэтому **для сервера это недостаточно надёжно**. Например, если сделать ветку с названием `origin/production` (это возможно!), она тоже выведется. Но в повседневной работе с Git такое обычно не вытворяют, разве что случайно, по незнанию.

На сервере хорошо бы быть максимально строгим:

```
git show-ref --verify --hash refs/remotes/origin/production
#            ^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ в удалённых ветках
# искать по точному совпадению и грохнуться с ошибкой, если ветки нет
```

Comment: А если не из локальных, а удаленных? Пытаюсь разобраться с `git ls-remote`, но не выходит получить конкретную ветку, ее SHA.

Comment: А вообще... Странно. Я сливаю из репозитория командой `git clone`, но по вашему примеру я получаю очень старый коммит. Такое впечатление, что лог просто перестал писаться и по вашим командам я не могу получить актуальную информацию.

Comment: `git clone git@bitbucket.org:my_name/best-repo.git -b production path/to/space`

Comment: @Colibri обновил ответ. Приведённые ранее команды актуальны для локальных веток, если они показывают старые коммиты, значит локальные ветки отстают от удалённых, только и всего.

Comment: Блин. Последняя команда все равно вернула тоже самое, что и самая первая `git show-ref --heads --hash production`. Они все ссылаются на один и тот же старый коммит.

Comment: @Colibri значит, либо на сервере действительно старый коммит, либо репозитории на Bitbucket и на сервере в разных состояниях.

Comment: Значит в разных состояниях, ибо я уже несколько дней (несколько раз) слил на сервер из того репозитория. Но у меня тогда вопрос, о котором вы уже наверно догадалис... :) Как привести их в одно состояние и почему это произошло? Ведь я всегда выполнял только ту комманду, что привел выше.

Comment: Хм-м... `git fetch`?

Comment: Ой лол. Спасибо :)

Comment: Отличный ответ!